# Openshift: Visibility between pods

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I'm trying to get access to a deployed postgresql pod from other pod.

Inside pod1 is running a straightforward postgresql container. By other side, in pod2 I'm running a vault container.

I'm trying to configure vault in order to add a database engine:

```
vault write database/config/my-postgresql-database \
    plugin_name=postgresql-database-plugin \
    allowed_roles="my-role" \
    connection_url="postgresql://{{username}}@postgresql:5432/" \
    username="postgres"
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
Error writing data to database/config/my-postgresql-database: Error making API request.

URL: PUT https://vault.ra-sec.svc/v1/database/config/my-postgresql-database
Code: 400. Errors:

* error creating database object: error verifying connection: pq: SSL is not enabled on the server
```

It seems that there's a connection related problem.

Could you provide me any ideas to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have setup Vault with PostgreSQL DB in our openshift environment.

> Configure config.hcl for Vault

Define a configuration file for Vault server.

```
#config.hcl
disable_mlock = true

storage "postgresql" {
  connection_url = "postgres://vault:vault@postgresql:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_disable = 1
}
```

where **postgresql is the service name** configured for PostgreSQL DB

> Startup Script

Run the server by using the below command by configuring it as part of your startup script.

```
vault server -config=/etc/service/vault-server/config.hcl
```

> Setup PostgreSQL DB

You can use the **PostgreSQL-peristent template** that is provided by Openshift(hope you are using the same). Execute the following commands in postgreSQL POD/container to allow the connection from Vault.

```
CREATE TABLE vault_kv_store (
  parent_path TEXT COLLATE "C" NOT NULL,
  path        TEXT COLLATE "C",
  key         TEXT COLLATE "C",
  value       BYTEA,
  CONSTRAINT pkey PRIMARY KEY (path, key)
);

CREATE INDEX parent_path_idx ON vault_kv_store (parent_path);
```

Setting up DB for vault: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage/postgresql.html

After this **make sure to create a service for PostgreSQL so that other PODs in the same namespace can discover them using the Openshift service name**.

Hope this helps! Anything missing let me know.